# How do I create an IF statement based on a Jekyll category?

Tags: jekyll

I want to conditionally add a class to `<body>` if a post is in the "article" category. I tried the following:

```
<body
  {% if page.categories == article %}
    class="article"
  {% endif %}
>
```

Strangely, this places the "article" class on every page except article posts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `contains` :

```
<body {% if page.categories contains "jekyll" %} class="article"{% endif %}>
```

All on one line otherwise you will have line breaks in your tag.